# Possible bug in pgfmanual: pgfkeys with /.initial handler works not as expected

Tags: pgfkeys

I am a bit surprised by the behavior of pgfkeys. To make my point clear, let me give you a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}
Output:
\pgfkeys{
  /foo/.initial=3,
  % /foo/.default=5,
  /foo
}
\end{document}
```

When looking at the pgfmanual (version 3.1.9a on page 988 at the top of the page, chapter *Defining Value-, Macro-, If- and Choice-Keys*), the user of the `pgfkeys` package is warned that directly calling an initialized key will result in it be reset to `\pgfkeysnovalue`. So, I expect in the code above to see only `Output:` on the page.

In reality, I get a page with `Output: 3`. It seems, that the value **is in fact printed out** contrary to the explicit statement in the documentation.

When deactivating the comment, no number is output. Here, the value seems to be configured when `/foo` is called. Thus, it will be equivalent to `/foo=5` and thus set the value.

I am neither sure if I get the point in the documentation correct and you see the discrepancy. If yes, I'd put a message to the developers to either fix the bug in the code or the docs.

Comment: That's a clear documentation mismatch, imho, and the code looks like the observed behaviour is deliberate, so I suggest raising a bug report for a documentation mismatch (the case is explicitly caught as there is a `\ifx\pgfkeyscurrentvalue\pgfkeysnovalue@text` check, but I guess it wasn't in the past).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this to be a bug and opened  an issue ([crossref](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1133)) against the repo to raise the awareness of the developers.